# copied a UITable to a other Storyboard, now I cannot see any rows?

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.2, storyboard, copy-paste, uistoryboard

copied a UITable to a other Storyboard, now I cannot see any rows ?
I Hade a nice looking and working Table with many rows linked to a nice View. Everything was perfect, Than I copy/paste the NavigationController, TableView and the corresponding View to a new project, I also imported the necessarily files (if I forgor someone, Xcode reminded me)

Running the new project code, works fine until I push in to the "old" tableView
nothing in the view is visible?
It might interesting to know that the title, and the addButton(upper right) EditButton(upper left) that I have in the TableView is there thou the addButton crasch the program. with the error mag something like "Invalid table view update"  Im thinking that this has to do with my AppDelegate.hm ?
The new project have files called StartAppDelegate.hm
But all table info is in the "old" AppDelegate.m so maybe connect them in some way?

Am I on to something or just wasting my time?

I please you all to help if you have any idea, I guess this is some rookie mistake but I cannot find any info surfing around.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting Some attributes in Various Inspector of your View and TableView. There  might  be a Small mistak...

Comment: quick response, nice =)
Im now quite sure that I know how you mean.
You see, not even setting the 'old' NavigationController as "initial View" will bring rows into my table

Comment: fyi,  I copied my Stuff from </br>
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.....

into the StartAppDelegate, first it f*uckup the run completly, then I did it all again (4min agon) and now i got rows in the table! =)

I think the mayor problem is fixed, but i do not know why...

Should I delete the old AppDelegate.hm and just stuck with the new one, is it not possible to have multi AppDelegate for lets say different table along the appplication

Comment: no. I was to fast with the good information, let me state whats accualy going on:  <br/>

(1) Adding the stuff from AppDelegate.m in to the new startAppDelegate.m will make the table show rows if and only if the old NavigationController is set as "initial view"  <br/>
  <br/>
(2) Not adding the stuff will make the rest of the application run, but will NOT show info/rows in tableView.  <br/>

I need a way to get the application working with the info/rows in the table.... Any one had this problem before?

Comment: Aha The problem is that I in the AppDelegate.m have a line like  
UINavigationController *popNavController = (UINavigationController *) self.windo.rootWviewController;  

And when Im moved the initial view so it is not the first view, of course it doesn't show any in the current viwe.  

So please help me change this line to point to the current view